# What happens when rendering on monitors connected to different GPUs

Tags: macos, opengl

I have multiple GPU with my MAC, with a secondary display connected to an external GPU. On switching my application between monitors I observe that the renderer for the OpenGL context gets updated to show the renderer for the current monitors. But, I can also specify the renderer I want to choose for my application in the `NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute`. On specifying the renderer, the specified renderer is always used, no matter where I switch my application to.

So, when I am trying to draw to a monitor which is connected to a GPU different from the one specified as the preferred renderer, how does the final rendering occur?
Is it like, it renders on the GPU on which the context is made and then copies it to the GPU connected to the monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it like, it renders on the GPU on which the context is made and then copies it to the GPU connected to the monitor?

Yes. In the [discussion of virtual screens](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_pg_concepts/opengl_pg_concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH208-SW16) in the OpenGL Programming Guide for Mac, it says that's what happens when a window spans two displays that are driven by different GPUs:

> When a window is split between multiple virtual screens, the framebuffer is rasterized entirely by the renderer driving the screen that contains the largest segment of the window. The regions of the window on the other virtual screens are drawn by copying the rasterized image.

(Note that splitting windows like that can only happen if System Preferences > Mission Control > "Displays have separate Spaces" is off.)

I expect the same thing applies in your case.